# Why does this program not loop when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, loops

I am having issues trying to loop a part of a program I have developed. There are 9 random strings of different colors, and 9 random colors of the corresponding string. For example a red "Yellow" may be displayed. I have buttons of each of the 9 colors, and the user gets a point added to their score each time a button of the color the string represents is pressed. I know that the scoring works just fine, I have tested it and a point is awarded at the tight time. My issue is that once a colored button is pressed, I intend for a new randomly colored random string to be outputted. This does not happen, the same string of same color remains on the screen. Here is the relevant code:

I would like it to loop whenever the user clicks any button, right or wrong. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: i don´t get it, there is no loop? So what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I don't see any loop here. You probably intend to put all this code inside a loop.

Comment: The program doesn't loop because... there's no loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (true) {`

This is entirely useless. It does nothing. `true` will always be equal to `true`, so  this will never affect your program. I wouldn't be surprised if it's optimized out entirely.

You likely intended to write

```
while (true) {
```

But, since you managed to mix up `if` and `while` (assuming that's what the problem is), I STRONGLY urge you to take a step back and review the basics before going any further. Make sure you understand exactly what `if` and `while` (at the very least) do.

Comment: you're absolutly right. Up-vote for that but I think his problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @TomWellbrock I wouldn't be surprised if there was other issues. I interpreted the question mainly with respect to the title though, which is why I focused solely on the looping aspect. Now that I read the question again though (post-edit), he does mention stuff you cover in your answer.

Comment: Here's the thing, I used if(true) on a previous program and it worked just fine. I took your advice and replaced it with while(true) and it gave me an error on a countdowntimer i had beneath the loop, that wasn't an issue as I just moved the ctd above the loop and it was fine. My problem is, once replacing 'if' with 'while', the app would crash every time I pressed the button in which the program shown is withing (code in OP is part of another onClick of a button which starts the game altogether). Now I click the starter button and my app freezes the emulator, before being prompted to back out

Comment: @H3ll0 You need to realize that, as I mentioned, if(true) does nothing; ever. It will never cause looping. In your other program, you must have been using some other looping mechanism; explicit or recursive. Youll need to debug why exactly you're getting the errors. To answer your main question, to loop, you'll need to wrap all this code in a loop.

Comment: Yeah turns out the other loop was working not because of if(true), thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Youre question is quite confusing but I think I understand what you want to do.

if i get you right.

> - you've got individual different colored buttons
> - each button contains a String which is also colored in a randomized color

Your Problem:

> - if the user clicks a button which color corresponds to the color of its text you want to change both of its colors randomised. And that
>     does not happen.
> - also you seem to misunderstand the basics of GUI there is no need to wrap your code in an inifite loop. The Gui runs in a seperated Thread (Event Dispacher Thread). It only terminates when you close it. with System.exit(0) for example. *Note: a better way is to set a defaultCloseOperation.*

And now what you have to do. Lets take this ActionListener as Example:

```
 purpleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (colorString[decider] == colorString[5]) {
                            score++;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

There is no mechanism to change the color of your "word" attribute at all.
You want to alter your "words" color:

```
purpleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (colorString[decider] == colorString[5]) {
                                score++;
                                changeTextColor();
                            }
                        }
                    });

private void changeTextColor(){
    int[] androidColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
    int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
    this.word.setTextColor(randomAndroidColor);
}
```

What I expect by providing this snipped of code is, that you have a `global attribute word`. If you want to display a word on every individual Button create a new class that extends JButton with a global word attribute and the method mentioned above. Something like:

```
class ButtonWithLabel extends JButton{


    public ButtonWithLabel(ActionListener onClickListener, Color color, String text){
    this.setName(text);
    this.setForegroundColor(color)
    this.addActionListener(onClickListener);
    }

    public void changeLabel(Color color, String text){
    this.setName(text);
    this.setForegroundColor(color)
    }
}
```

I dont have an IDE at hand so there might be some typos.

Comment: The individual string is displayed in a text view above the buttons, sorry if that wasn't made clear. Not text on the buttons.

Comment: nonetheless I provided solutions for both cases